# Query to database for showing all images from same tag

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have page where are shown images from database and under the images are tags for each image. 
database tables are:
images

```
image_id
image_name
etc
```

tag

```
tag_id
tag_name
```

tags_images

```
tag_id
image_id
```

Under the image I select and show them like this

```
<li>Tags: </li>';
            $tags = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `images` p LEFT JOIN `tags_image` tp ON p.image_id = tp.image_id LEFT JOIN `tag` t ON tp.tags_id = t.tag_id WHERE p.image_id = ?");
            $tags -> bindParam(1, $row['image_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $tags -> execute();
            foreach($tags as $tag) {
                echo '<li><a href="tagsPreview.php?tag_id='.$tag['tag_id'].'">'.$tag['tag_name'].'</li>';  
            }
```

Now I want when user click on the href link on the tagsPreview.php page to load all images which have this tag. What I tried is

```
if(isset($_GET['tag_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['tag_id'])){
                    $tag_id = $_GET['tag_id']; {                         

$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from `images` i 
                         INNER JOIN `tags_image` ti ON i.image_id = ti.image_id 
                         WHERE ti.tags_id = ? ASC LIMIT 20");

$result -> bindParam(1, $row['tag_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result -> execute();
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    // images
}
```

The problem is that I get empty page with no images.

Comment: `ASC LIMIT 20"` without `order by` clause ?

Comment: More specifically, the `ASC` generates an error and your code should be checking for errors.

Comment: Ok, I really forgot about ORDER BY .. now I've put it `ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 20` but no change

Comment: perhaps you need `ORDER BY i.image_id  LIMIT 20`

Comment: Shouldn't be there `$result -> bindParam(1, $row['tag_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);` passed `$tag_id` variable instead `$row['tag_id']`?

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. `$result -> bindParam(1, $row['tag_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);` with `$tag_id` everything is working. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure to accept @AmrutGaikwad's answer below and add error checking to all of your PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$result -> bindParam(1, $row['tag_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

with

```
$result -> bindParam(1, $tag_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Thank you once again for the help!